# TIL-library EffCompressor: getInputRotary is structurally singular when Inertia

Tags: modelica

I am fairly new at working with the TIL-library (v. 3.12.0) in Dymola2022. I am trying to include some inertia in the current compressor models of the TIL-library. To start simple, I choose the EffCompressor as base model. The base model already has following equations using tau and w.

```
w = 2 PI n
tau = shaftPower / max(w, 1e-6)
```

The shafpower is calculated based on refrigerant mass flow and enthalpy at inlet and outlet.

If no mechanical port is used n is given a constant value using a model parameter and getInputsRotary.rotaryFlange.phi =0. In this case w is calculated using the first equation and than used to calculate tau using the second.

If a mechanical port is used, w=der(getInputsRotary.rotaryFlange.phi) and tau = getInputsRotary.rotatoryFlange.tau; (These values can be given by use of a RotaryBoundary)

My goal is to impose the inertia of the compressor (by defining its moment of inertia) and as such influence the change of rotational speed. I thus extended this model and added one unknown and 1 equation:

parameter Modelica.Units.SI.Inertia J = 1; (Parameter because I want to insert its value. Random value to test equations)

equation
tau=J*der(w);

The problem is this causes a singularity in the getInputsRotary-model, which only contains a rotational flange (with passes the phi and tau value from the RotaryBoundary).

I do not understand why this model because structurally singular (as I added one unknown and one equation). Defining J as a variable solves the problem with the model check, but gives a singularity error when running the model in a simple tester. Besides, the J should not be variable as it is a compressor property.)

I added the parameter J representing the moment of inertia. This results in a structurally singular problem. Also variants on this, by defining it as a variable, giving it an imposed value or not, etc. give the same problem.

What I would like to happen is that the change in rotational speed of the compressor accounts for the inserted moment of inertia without making the problem structurally singular.

Does anyone know why the problem becomes structurally singular and how I could address this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of modifying equations of a component model out of a library I would always prefer to extend the system model (graphically) by using additional components.

In your case you can easily do that by mixing TIL components with MSL (Modelica Standard Library) components. The mechanical connector from TIL is compatible to Modelica.Mechanics.Rotational components.

Adding inertia would look like that:

[image]

Comment: If it is just an inertia I would leave the left-flange of the inertia hanging without anything connected.